# Git squash commits of renamed files (an keep history)

Tags: git, rename, git-rebase, squash, git-squash

**Backround**

Hi, I'm working on a local feature branch. This local branch is messed up with lots of small commits. Before pushing the branch to the remote I would like to tidy things up.

For this I'd do a interactively rebase:

```
git rebase -i
```

No problem so far.

**Problem**

Now here's the difficult part:
During the development of the feature I've done several refactorings including *renames* and *moves* of files.
The history of the renamed files are available, due to renaming them with:

```
git -mv
```

But when I squash the commits before and after the rename-commits, the history is gone and git notifies the changes as deletion and addition of a file.

What is the Problem?

*How can I squash commits including rename without loosing file history?*

Answer (score 8):

Git does not track renames directly, it compares file contents and detects renames by similarity.

When you squash a history you put all changes of a file in one commit. The file might then change a lot compared to the previous commit. Thus it is not very similar to the previous commit and git thinks it is a delete/add.

if you want to see the history of such a file you must adjust the `find-renames` threshold. E.g. for 50% similarity use

```
git log --follow --find-rename=50 -- someFile
```

Similar options are also available for `diff`, `merge` and `rebase`.
Take a look at the docs:

[git rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.2.0)

> rename-threshold=n
>   Controls the similarity threshold used for rename detection. See also git-diff[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.2.0) -M.

[git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

> --find-renames[=n]
>
> Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%. **The default similarity index is 50%**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, renaming files with `git mv`actually doesn't tell git to keep the history of a file, instead it just renames the file and later it auto detects that the file has been renamed?
In other words: there is no possibility to do what I wanted? The only possibility is to do the rename in a separate commit.

Comment: Is there a way for forcing the git to recognize a file as rename instead of new file by specifying a similarity when checking in?

Comment: Wow this is shocking news and really bad. I always preached **Do a rename with `git mv` to allow git to track the rename** to git newbees and now I am also stuck in an impossible rebase of commits that renamed files heavily.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I often had problems when one git commit contains a lot of changes to a file as well as it's rename. This often happens when developers squash a lot of commits. I usually prefer to either rename or change a file in one commit. Of course in some languages like Java a move will also change the source file's content since there is a package declaration, but this is a small content change and git can easily track it.

Comment: @RenéLink Yep, small commits are key. I basically squashed only those commits containing no renames after posting my last comment.